# CSS/Bootstrap to wrap a text on the side of a rounded image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code below that shows a username and a location. I want to wrap the text below the username, but on the side of the rounded image. Can anyone help me?

Currently:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="avatar.png" class="img-circle" />
    <a href="user.html" class="publisher-name">Username</a>
    <div class="post-location">
        Location
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {background: #fff;padding: 16px; }
.header img{width: 36px;height: 36px;}
.header a.publisher-name {margin-left: 6px;color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);font- 
    weight: 500;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: middle;font-family: 
    "Roboto", sans-serif; }
a.publisher-name {margin: 0;}
.post-location { font-size: 12px; margin-top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to wrap the username and location with another div:

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="avatar.png" class="img-circle" />
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="user.html" class="publisher-name">Username</a>
    <div class="post-location">
        Location
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, remove the margin-left on the username and add this CSS for your new wrapper class:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing **Flex**!

```css
.header {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
}

.header img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.header a.publisher-name {
  margin-left: 6px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font- weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family:
    "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

a.publisher-name {
  margin: 0;
}

.post-location {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="avatar.png" class="img-circle" />
  <div>
    <a href="user.html" class="publisher-name">Username</a>
    <div class="post-location">
      Location
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To do this, simply wrap the two elements you want on the RHS in a `div`, so that when you apply `flex` it treats the `img` and `div` like columns!

More on Flex here: [How TO - Two Column Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange in groups vertically or horizontally together, not to fit horizontally and vertically! 
- tag img 
- tag a and div tag 
=> edit the layout of each group.